# fatal: remote error: Invalid authentication credentials. when pushing code to google app repo

Tags: git, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-source-repos

I just started learning about google cloud and I successfully deployed a simple web app I wrote in flask and it woked fine. But when I tried to push a modification a couple of hours later, I get this error:

```
fatal: remote error:
Invalid authentication credentials.

Please generate a new identifier:
https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?
scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Heres my `git config --list`:

```
user.name=my_name
user.email=myemail@gmail.com
credential.helper=cache --timeout 80000
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/my/project.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
credential.helper=gcloud.sh
remote.google.url=https://source.developers.google.com/p/myapp-
11111/r/myapp
remote.google.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/google/*
```

I did not change anything on the gcloud console in that time. In fact, I did not change anything on the computer as I was not working on anything. What is this error and how to rectify it?

Comment: By "push" do you mean a GAE app deployment or literally a `git push` command? How exactly are you trying to push (the commandline I mean) and, if somehow available, how exactly did you push the 1st time?

Comment: It sounds like you're having issues with Cloud Source Repositories, independently of App Engine. I see that you have 2 different entries for credential.helper, which might conflict with the Google provided credential helper. You could try clearing your git configuration and following the instructions for [adding a repository as a remote](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes) from scratch.